# Delete record in firebase with Javascript - Vuejs

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

I am able to show all data from my products record in Firebase DB, what i want now is to delete a certain record that i select.

I got a bit of the documentation of Firebase but i'm not so good with VueJs, although i think this is more of a JavaScript problem.

What i get on my console when i click the delete link is:

> Error: Firebase.child failed: First argument was an invalid path:
>   "undefined". Paths must be non-empty strings and can't contain ".",
>   "#", "$", "[", or "]"

Here is my code:

```
<template>
<tbody v-for="(key, value, index) in products">
    <tr v-for="k, val in key">
        <td>{{ k.name }}</td>
        <td>{{ k.description }}</td>
        <td>{{ k.oldPrice }}</td>
        <td>{{ k.price }}</td>
        <td>{{ k.prodId }}</td>
        <td>{{ k.sellerName }}</td>
        <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-delete-style" v-on:click="removeProduct(k)" title="Delete Product"></span></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</template>

<script>
removeProduct: function (product) {
  console.log("Product:" + product);
  productsRef.child(product['.key']).remove();
  toastr.success("Product deleted successfully");
}
</script>
```

Below you can see my DB:

[image]
Any help is appreciated, Thank you.

Comment: what value do you get in `product['.key']`

Comment: I get undefined

Comment: I cannot get the record with that key

Comment: you should use $key

Comment: dont know much about vue.js, but looks like you are passing a string to product[] that is y it is undefined. So first try to make sure that this `productsRef.child(product['.key']).remove();` actually works, by passing in a hardcoded key. Then if that works, figure out how to get the key and pass it to the same expresion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reference first to that record and then call the `remove` function, here is an example:

```
<template>
  <tbody v-for="(key, value, index) in products">
      <tr v-for="k, val in key">
          <td>{{ k.name }}</td>
          <td>{{ k.description }}</td>
          <td>{{ k.oldPrice }}</td>
          <td>{{ k.price }}</td>
          <td>{{ k.prodId }}</td>
          <td>{{ k.sellerName }}</td>
          <td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash btn-delete-style" v-on:click="removeProduct(k, k.sellerId, k.prodId)" title="Delete Product"></span></td>
      </tr>
  </tbody>
</template>
<script>
  removeProduct: function (product, sellerID, prodId) {
    var currentRef = db.ref('products/' + sellerID + '/' + prodId);
    currentRef.remove();
    toastr.success("Product deleted successfully");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: This is it, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think you should take product id from prodid

```
productsRef.child(product['prodid']).remove()
```